# Not able to Install python package libportaudio-dev via pip on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, pip

Python Version : 2.7.13

Pip Version: 9.0.1

Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libportaudio-dev(from version:)

No matching distribution found for libportaudio-dev

[image]

Comment: Please don't show errors as screenshots. Copy the text, [edit] your question and put the text there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` installs packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libportaudio-dev) and there is no libportaudio-dev at PyPI. It's not a Python package. It is [a package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/devel/libportaudio-dev) in Ubuntu.

To install it on w32 you have to [download](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html) the source code and compile it. See [the instructions](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html).

There are old precompiled binaries at https://github.com/adfernandes/precompiled-portaudio-windows

https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries — these ones look more fresh.

Comment: Based on this page: https://pythonspot.com/en/speech-recognition-using-google-speech-api/comment-page-3/#comment-1817                                         I need to install libportaudio-dev, python-dev                              libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev                           
SpeechRecognition in my Windows 64-bit System.                                      Kindly help me out in that as these commands are for Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need any of this. Anyway the instructions are for Ubuntu. See my other answer.

Comment: The link to the **Ubuntu package** doesn't exist/work. I'm editing this post and marking it as *`BROKEN`*.