# cant install PyAudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, python-3.8

I tried to install `PyAudio` but facing following errors:

```
    Collecting PyAudio
    Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
    Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python3.8\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pizhlo21\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5pn6g8qb\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pizhlo21\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5pn6g8qb\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pizhlo21\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zv7fvd9r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python3.8\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\pizhlo21\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5pn6g8qb\PyAudio\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python3.8\include -Ic:\python3.8\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python3.8\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pizhlo21\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5pn6g8qb\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pizhlo21\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5pn6g8qb\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pizhlo21\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zv7fvd9r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python3.8\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

> python version 3.8
>
> pip version 20.0.2

Please help me in finding a solution. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308564/7976758 and https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score -1):

You need install Visual Studio 2019. No file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe and etc.

Comment: i've already installed both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2019

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include#33821084

Comment: i also get an error installing portaudio:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PortAudio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PortAudio

but i've downloaded PortAudio

Comment: First you need install portaudio. Try another version of it or other version of python . Maybe 3.7 will work good.